# Displaying primes from 2-10,000 in C

Tags: c, primes

I'm struggling with this (optional) problem my professor recommended I try. Basically, my task is to write a program which displays all prime integers from 2-10,000 using my own user-defined function to determine prime-ness. It sounded simple enough but I'm having major difficulties debugging my program. For some reason, my code only displays 2 and 3 before ending.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//function declaration
int prime(int);
//main body
int main(void)
{
    int x=2, y;
    for (x=2;x<=30;x++)
    {
        y=prime(x);
        if (y!=0)
            printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
//function definition
int prime(int x)
{
    int y;
    for (y=2; y<=(int)sqrt(x); ++y)
    {
        if (x%y==0)
           return 0;
    }
    if (y==(int)sqrt(x))
       return 1;
}
```

Instead of returning 1 if x is prime, my prime checking function seems to return a random large number (2686xxx) but that shouldn't be an issue because all primes return 0. If I run something like:

```
if (y==0)
    printf("%d\n", x);
```

I see a list of all non prime numbers. If I run something like:

```
printf("%d    %d\n", x, y);
```

I see a list of all integers from 2-10,000 and the result of my prime checking function (0 for non-primes, 2686xxx for primes).

Why doesn't the opposite (y!=0) display a list of prime numbers? What is causing my code to stop after just displaying 2 and 3? Why is my prime function returning a weird integer instead of 1? Finally, I'm still a beginner but how can I write better code in general? I don't think I'm breaking any of the standard accepted practices but how can I make my code more clean or efficient?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Mentally follow through what your `prime` function does if `x` is 3. You should be able to see why it returns a nonsense value. (Hint: 2 is greater than `(int)sqrt(3)` right?)

Comment: make sure that all paths of a function have a return statement. your `prime` function does not.

Comment: Related: Consider building a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), and pulling out all the primes when done. You need an array of flags, a nested loop, and some simple math. Review the linked article for details on the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop *continues* if `y==(int)sqrt(x)`. So when it *finishes*, they're not equal. What you wanted is:

```
if (y>=(int)sqrt(x))
   return 1;
```

But this is not needed at all. Just `return 1;` is sufficient. You've already returned zero if the number isn't prime.

If you wanted only a single return statement:

```
int prime(int x)
{
    bool isPrime = true;
    int y;
    for (y=2; y<=(int)sqrt(x); ++y)
    {
        if (x%y==0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me just quickly check if I understand my error.

After completing the loop, y==(int)sqrt(x)+1 so what I originally wrote wouldn't return anything. Writing an if statement was completely unnecessary though because all non-primes would already have returned 0.

A function breaks after returning something right? I was originally worried that removing the if condition would make every integer return 1 but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @muri The `return` statement not only lets you return something, it also returns to the caller. I updated my answer to show how to do this with only a single return statement without extra tests.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the sqrt() function. In mathematics if you have 'x = sqrt(y)'. If you square both sides you will get something like this 'x * x = y'. This expression in c is tremendously faster than the sqrt function. Thus instead of doing:

```
y <= (int)sqrt(x)
```

Have you for loop guard be something like this:

```
y * y <= x
```

Here is a running example of your problem:

[Primes 2 -> 10000](http://ideone.com/mZNOSx)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your prime function just return 1. If it wasn't prime it would have returned 0 earlier. Right?

As it is you've made a function which sometimes returns nothing at all. Which means that it returns whatever random value happens to be in the register.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sieve of eratosthenes or sieve of atkin to mark all the prime numbers in an array and then display the prime numbers. It will be time efficient although it incurs some space complexity.

e.g if you want to display prime numbers from 1 to 10

Leave of 1. Its not a prime. Its neither prime nor composite.

So start from 2.

consider this array of size 10 = 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Traverse from 2. If an element is not highlighted highlight all its multiples.

i.e for 2 highlight its multiples 4 6 8 10

==>  2 3 **4** 5 **6** 7 **8** 9 **10**

For 3 do the same

==>  2 3 **4** 5 **6** 7 **8** 
**9** 
**10**

Then do it for the rest of the no.s i.e. 5 and 10 (Here 7 dont have multiple)

Finally print the non highlighted elements. 2,3,5,7.

Repeat this procedure for any other ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in writing computer programs for prime numbers, perhaps you would like to turn this paper into a computer program. It deals with prime numbers and is similar to the sieve you were trying to create in C.

https://graviticpropulsion.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/prime-number-theory.pdf

I'm not sure if it is faster or less memory intensive, but I'm curious myself how high of a prime number it can find before it becomes too intensive for a computer.